# How can I rename column in laravel using migration?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, migration

I have columns as mentioned bellow:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('stnk', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('no_reg', 50)->unique();
        $table->string('no_bpkb', 50)->unique();
        $table->string('nama_pemilik', 100);
        $table->string('alamat');
        $table->string('merk', 50);
        $table->string('tipe', 50);
        $table->string('jenis', 50);
        $table->smallInteger('tahun_pembuatan');
        $table->smallInteger('tahun_registrasi');
        $table->smallInteger('isi_silinder');
        $table->string('no_rangka', 50);
        $table->string('no_mesin', 50);
        $table->string('warna', 50);
        $table->string('bahan_bakar', 50);
        $table->string('warna_tnkb', 50);
        $table->string('kode_lokasi', 50);
        $table->date('berlaku_sampai');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->index('created_at');
        $table->index('updated_at');
    });

}
```

**I have made seeder to stnk table**

Now I want to rename `id` to `id_stnk`.
I've added a **"doctrine / dbal"** in the **"composer"** and do a `composer update`.

I've made migration `php artisan migration:make rename_column`. 
Then I've added new method to rename_column:

```
Schema::table('stnk', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->renameColumn('id', 'id_stnk');

});
```

And then I've tried to run command `php artisan migrate` but I got error as mentioned bellow:

```
[Ulluminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './my_database/#sql -447_33' to './my_database/stnk' (error: 150) (SQL: ALTER TABLE stnk CHANGE id id_stnk INT UNSIGENED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL)

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025  Error on rename  of './my_database/#sql -447_33' to './my_database/stnk' (error: 150)
```

Answer (score 197):

You need to create another migration file - and place it in there:

Run

```
Laravel 4:    php artisan migrate:make rename_stnk_column
Laravel 5+:    php artisan make:migration rename_stnk_column
```

Then inside the new migration file place:

```
class RenameStnkColumn extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('stnk', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('id', 'id_stnk');
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('stnk', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('id_stnk', 'id');
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: i have eddit my question above, look at now.. i have error message in gitbash

Comment: Error 150 is a foreign key restraint. It means you have other tables that reference the `id` on the `stnk` table.

Comment: Also for column renaming to work, you need to require a package that was removed in L5 `"doctrine/dbal": "~2.3"` Without that you get some very obscure errors. It was raised as a bug here https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3116 and with an arguably less useful mention in the documentation here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#renaming-columns

Comment: Once the migration was done, should the file be deleted and the original create schema updated? Just asking how to keep things clean

Comment: If you've updated to L10 or L11 you may need to run: `composer require doctrine/dbal:*`

Answer (score 54):

Follow these steps, respectively for rename column migration file.

**1-** Is there Doctrine/dbal library in your project. If you don't have run the command first

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

**2-** create update migration file for update old migration file.
Warning (need to have the same name)

```
php artisan make:migration update_oldFileName_table
```

for example my old migration file name: create_users_table
update file name should : update_users_table

**3-** update_oldNameFile_table.php

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->renameColumn('from', 'to');
});
```

'from' my old column name and 'to' my new column name

**4-** Finally run the migrate command

```
php artisan migrate
```

**Source link:** [laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#modifying-columns)

**NOTE:** This feature supports from laravel 5.x to 8.x version.

**UPDATE:**
This process got even easier after version 9
All you have to do is use the "rename" static method of the "Schema" facade.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
 
Schema::rename($from, $to);
```

**Source link:** [laravel document-9.x](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#renaming-and-dropping-tables)

Comment: Yes, these steps are correct, you can change the name of the field after installing the package.

Answer (score 44):

first thing you want to do is to create your migration file.

Type in your command line

```
php artisan make:migration rename_stk_column --table="YOUR TABLE" --create
```

After creating the file. Open the new created migration file in your app folder under database/migrations.

In your up method insert this:

```
Schema::table('stnk', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->renameColumn('id', 'id_stnk');
    });
}
```

and in your down method:

```
    Schema::table('stnk', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->renameColumn('id_stnk', 'id);
    });
}
```

then in your  command line just type

```
php artisan migrate
```

Then wollah! you have just renamed id to id_stnk. 
BTW you can use

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

to undo the changes. Goodluck

Comment: i have eddit my question above, look at now.. i have error message in gitbash

Comment: Be sure to add the doctrine/dbal dependency to your composer.json file.

Answer (score 21):

## Renaming Columns *(Laravel 5.x)*

To rename a column, you may use the renameColumn method on the Schema builder. *Before renaming a column, be sure to add the [***doctrine/dbal***](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/dbal) dependency to your composer.json file.*

Or you can simply required the package using composer...

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

**Source:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#renaming-columns

**Note:** Use **make:migration** and not *migrate:make* for Laravel 5.x

Dropping Doctrine dependency when renaming database columns starting with Laravel 9 [#45258](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/45258)

Comment: Just dont use any columns as an ENUM in the table you are trying to edit. Doctrine/dbal does not know what this is.....

I had to change the original migration to be correct name at the start and reset whole database.  Lucky I was still in development. 

I would of though Laravel & Co would make this a dependency in composer from the start?

Comment: @mikoop It originaly was a dependency from the start, in earlier versions of the framework. But this dependency is too heavy and not commonly used. So it has been removed. (This is the summary; there were lots of discussion before the decision. In fact, community has asked for its removal, and has been heard.)

Comment: renameColumn was deprecated in doctrine, and currently removed.

Answer (score 15):

Throwing my $0.02 in here since none of the answers worked, but did send me on the right path. What happened was that a previous foreign constraint was throwing the error. Obvious when you think about it.

So in your new migration's `up` method, first drop that original constraint, rename the column, then add the constraint again with the new column name. In the `down` method, you do the exact opposite so that it's back to the sold setting.

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('proxy4s', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // Drop it
        $table->dropForeign(['server_id']);

        // Rename
        $table->renameColumn('server_id', 'linux_server_id');

        // Add it
        $table->foreign('linux_server_id')->references('id')->on('linux_servers');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('proxy4s', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // Drop it
        $table->dropForeign(['linux_server_id']);

        // Rename
        $table->renameColumn('linux_server_id', 'server_id');

        // Add it
        $table->foreign('server_id')->references('id')->on('linux_servers');
    });
}
```

Hope this saves someone some time in the future!

Comment: "Throwing my $0.02"  

Answer (score 4):

To rename a column, you may use the renameColumn method on the Schema builder.

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->renameColumn('from', 'to');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

in my case I had named a column "avitar" and wanted it to be "avatar".

I ran:
`php artisan make:migration rename_avitar_in_users_table --table=users`

which generated the boilerplate file where I added:

$table->renameColumn('avitar', 'avatar');    // to the up

$table->renameColumn('avitar', 'avatar');    // to the down

```
public function up(): void
{

    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('avitar', 'avatar');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 */
public function down(): void
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('avitar', 'avatar');
    });
}
```

However, this did not work when I ran:

```
php artisan migrate
```

The fix was to install:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

I hope this helps somebody working through a similar issue.
-Steve

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I faced the same problem recently in **Laravel 7** application.
To make renaming columns work I used a tip from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65014592/2540699) answer where instead of `composer require doctrine/dbal` I have issued `composer require doctrine/dbal:^2.12.1` because the latest version of doctrine/dbal still throws an error.

Just keep in mind that if you already use a higher version, this answer might not be appropriate for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use a query DB statement if you don't want to use **doctrine/dbal** package. For example:

```
public function up()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE from to VARCHAR(200)');
}

public function down()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE to from VARCHAR(200)');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Just follow bellow steps**

Step 1: Install dbal package

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Step 2: Create migration and update like bellow

```
Schema::table('your original table name', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->renameColumn('old column name', 'new column name');
});
```

Step 3: Run artisan command

```
php artisan migrate
```

Full Description Links: https://www.webjourney.dev/how-to-rename-table-column-in-laravel-webjourney

Comment: yes after installing doctrine/dbal from composer it fixed my problem

Answer (score -1):

The above answer is great or if it will not hurt you, just rollback the migration and change the name and run migration again.

```
 php artisan migrate:rollback
```

Comment: i have eddit my question above, look at now.. i have error message in gitbash