# artisan migration error "Class 'Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOMySql\\Driver' not found",

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-5

When trying to run a migration I get the error Artisan migration

> error:`Class 'Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOMySql\\Driver' not found`

I have read the questions here and also see the notes to add:

`doctrine/dbal": "~2.3` in the requires section of composer.json

[Github Bug Report](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3116)

However, I don't understand what has happened. I created table a few days ago with no issue.

I can't figure out what to do after adding that dependency in composer.son.

I don't want to accidentally update any other packages.

Comment: Thanks! Nothing at all has changed. im trying to post the composer file

Comment: Are you using Artisan with Laravel or Symfony2?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

The `doctrine/dbal` dependency needs to be added to your `composer.json`

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

For more information check [laravel #Modifying Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#modifying-columns)

Comment: As an addition, i encountered this problem upon removing a debugbar dependency from composer.json. I did notice DBAL package being removed but it was no problem until i ran another migration. Once fireing `composer require` i then had a 'problem' with this: `composer/package-versions-deprecated`

Answer (score 100):

In my case  both composer install and composer install was not working giving a same error “Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found”,

The changes that i made to make this workable are given below

composer.json file changed

```
 "doctrine/dbal": "^3.0",
```

this changed with

```
"doctrine/dbal": "^2.0",
```

then run the command

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 41):

You have to downgrade the current version, this is what worked for me:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal:2.*
```

Comment: this is very simple way to downgrade. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks doctrine/dbal 2.13.9 works on laravel 8.10.0

Answer (score 15):

If you using doctrine 3, downgrade to `"doctrine/dbal": "^2.10.3"`(I don't know does laravel updated migration tools for doctrine 3. If do, you should update laravel tools).
They renamed class and  `Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOMySql\\Driver` not exists

Comment: Fixed now though, just run `composer update`

Answer (score 15):

**Laravel**

Who ever is facing this issue while having
doctrine/dbal": "3.0" aleady required:
downgrade it back to

```
"doctrine/dbal": "^2.10".
```

If you still face issues for example getting

> Laravel\Passport\Bridge\AccessToken::__toString() must not throw an
> exception

You should require a prev version of lcobucci/jwt. It just got auto updated to 3.4, which caused these issues for me.
Took me around 3-4 hours to track everything down to this.
Hope it helps someone else too.

```
composer require lcobucci/jwt 3.3.3
```

Comment: `composer require lcobucci/jwt 3.3.3` did help, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

```sh
# For Laravel 6x/7x:    
composer require doctrine/dbal:"^2.0"
    
# For Laravel >= 8x:    
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please "edit" to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed, my project was running 7.x.

Answer (score 11):

As already said, use `composer require doctrine/dbal`, if for whatever reason that doesn't work, use a lower version like `composer require doctrine/dbal:^2.12.1` and then run `composer dumpautoload -o`.

Answer (score 6):

Run

```
composer update
```

It will install your missing packages like PDOMySql.

**Or**

Delete vendor folder and run

```
composer install
```

Comment: It will not install any "missing packages" it will install what's specified in your `composer.json` file.

Comment: In my case just running "composer install" solved the issue for me. I am using Laravel 8.0.0 on windows 8.1 32bits. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4):

This message shows up if you want to edit column in a database.

To solve it do:

- add `doctrine/dbal` dependency to  `composer.json`
- and use the `composer require doctrine/dbal` command

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was due to the version of php that did not meet the necessary requirements for that version of the package.

So, **updating to any previous version is not the solution, you have to look at the requirements** of each version of the package and confirm that your project complies with them.

Here the specification of the requirements: https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/dbal#3.1.3

And the command to update the library would be:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal:number_of_your_indicated_version
```

For example:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal:^2.13.5
```

Answer (score 3):

Before modifying a column, be sure to add the doctrine/dbal dependency to your composer.json file. The Doctrine DBAL library is used to determine the current state of the column and create the SQL queries needed to make the specified adjustments to the column:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using laravel 7 then please downgrade the "doctrine/dbal"

From

```
doctrine/dbal:"^3.1"
```

To

```
doctrine/dbal:"^2.0"
```

and then run

```
composer update
```

It works for me

Answer (score 2):

just run

```
composer update
```

worked for me Laravel 8

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Laravel 8.

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
composer update
```

**didn't help** me to solve the issue.

I used   **DB::statement('SQLQuery')** to solve the issue.
I used below code to rename the column.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('customer_profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
      //  $table->renameColumn('user_type_id','plan_id');
    });
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `customer_profile` CHANGE `user_type_id` `plan_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL;');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you share your current composer.json?

After composer.json update, you can execute composer install. It won't update existing packages (because of generated composer.lock), it'll only install new ones.

What has changes since your last migration?

It's the same project in the same directory? If so, it should be there.

Comment: Hmm can't add that much code here. Well definitely nothing has changed. I am not sure how to run composer

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/

Install it, then check [How to use it](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#using-composer) and run composer install in your project directory.

Answer (score -2):

OK thanks so much for the help.
Stupidly, I had read that to do some other operations, that missing driver is called and I had tried to run a migration the other day to change a column name and what I completely forgot was that subsequent migrate runs are trying to still run that bad one. Once i remembered and deleted the update column name migration, my add table migration ran fine. With a project due in a few weeks, no package updates for me!!

Answer (score -2):

I saw this:
To rename a column, you may use the renameColumn method on the Schema builder. Before renaming a column, be sure to add the doctrine/dbal dependency to your composer.json file:

it maybe work.

Answer (score -2):

if you are using PhpStorm editor for your project open Terminal tab and run this command:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

[image]

also you can open command window in root of your project and run that command.

Comment: I believe this was covered in many of the above answers over the past 4 years.