# Laravel 5.0 - Rename multiple columns in 1 migration

Tags: laravel-5, migration

We recently made a switch of service provider such that multiple columns in a DB table for this project will need to be renamed.

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522292/how-can-i-rename-column-in-laravel-using-migration) post which shows how to rename 1 column from 1 table:

```
php artisan migrate:make rename_stk_column --table="YOUR TABLE" --create
```

Is there a way to execute this same migration with multiple columns ? (1 migration, not more than 1...trying to minimize number of migration files created)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add multiple renameColumn(); statements for each column that needs to be updated in that given table.  Just need to come up with a whatever name you guys/gals use for your migration files.

Just a sample of what I ran

```
class MultipleColumnUpdate extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
            $table->renameColumn('name', 'user_name');
            $table->renameColumn('email', 'work_email');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
            $table->renameColumn('user_name', 'name');
            $table->renameColumn('work_email', 'email');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Somehow, I'm not being able to do this on Laravel 5.3, it throws "there is no column 'old_name'"...

Comment: @giovannipds if you want to share your migration, I can take a look. I haven't used 5.3 yet or reviewed the change documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Nolan, but I got it sometime later. It was probably just an error in my database, of course it'd throw that message. =) 5.3 is almost the same of 5.2.

Comment: In case someone finds this in the future. SQLite seems to have problems with this. You need to use two separate Schema::table() calls, one for each column rename. Same goes for dropColumn statements.