# Change column in table have an enum type in postgres

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, doctrine, laravel-migrations

This is my code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('organization_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('company_id', 'organization_id');
    });
}
```

I want to rename column in table. And in this table have an column is enum type. But errors: Unknown database type company_roles requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSQL100Platform may
   not support it. I use laravel 5.6

Comment: can you show the migration where you created the table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522292/how-can-i-rename-column-in-laravel-using-migration this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

This issue may be related to what is mentioned in Laravel Docs "You can't rename columns in the table that has 'enum' type". See: [image]

I am afraid this is like 5 years old issue with Doctrine/DBal that Laravel uses see:[[Bug] Schema builder - renameColumn fails on table with enum columns](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1186) But one of the workarounds is also on the same issue report [DB Query](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1186#issuecomment-99484766). For reference sake I'll put it here:

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN column_name ENUM('Here','is','choices')");
```

In this case, you need to provide the right statement in the `down()` function of your migration class file to restore the state of the table.