# Laravel renameColumn results in an invalid SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am renaming a column with Laravel like so:

```
$table->renameColumn('salesforce_id', 'sfdc_parent_id');
```

This ends up with me getting a SQL that looks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE websites 
CHANGE salesforce_id sfdc_parent_id VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT ''NULL''
```

The double single quotes around the `NULL` valid make this query invalid.

Is this a bug is is something else going wrong here? I am currently using MariaDB:

```
0.3.10-MariaDB Homebrew
```

Surprisingly enough this only happens when I reverse the migration.

What could be going on here?

Comment: not sure , is this the problem. is there doctrine/dbal installed ?

Comment: Did the original column have a default value?

Comment: Hope this link helps: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522292/how-can-i-rename-column-in-laravel-using-migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522292/how-can-i-rename-column-in-laravel-using-migration)

Comment: I removed MariaDB and switched back to MySQL. There is an issue with MariaDB in combination with the renameColumn. That is why there are double single quotes around the null default. It works now. Laravel does not officially support MariaDB anyways.

Comment: See https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22050.