# Laravel: Rename table field without deleting data during migration

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, migration

I'm trying to change "name" into "username" without deleting the existing records.

I tried all of these but it just wipes out the data in the table.

```
php artisan *
     migrate:fresh       Drop all tables and re-run all migrations
     migrate:install     Create the migration repository
     migrate:refresh     Reset and re-run all migrations
     migrate:reset       Rollback all database migrations
     migrate:rollback    Rollback the last database migration
     migrate:status      Show the status of each migration
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I rename column in laravel using migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522292/how-can-i-rename-column-in-laravel-using-migration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have to follow below steps!

**1. install Doctrine/dbal**

> `composer require doctrine/dbal`

**2. create a migration file to rename column name**

> `php artisan make:migration updateTableColumnName`

**3. add below code to edit your column name**

> ```
> Schema::table('YourTableName', function (Blueprint $table) {
>     $table->renameColumn('name', 'username');
> });
> ```

And Run the migration you have done it without losing your data.

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I did the steps you mentioned, what is the migration command that I should use? Or what do I do next?

Comment: just run, php artisan migrate command. after doing above step. and your column name will be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 - php artisan make:migration rename_table
Step 2 - Schema::rename('old_table_name', 'new_table_name');
Step 3 - php artisan migrate

Answer (score 0):

> suppose you have 'table_name' table and you want to change column 'old_column_name' to 'new_column_name'

```
php artian make:migration rename_columns_to_table_name_table --table=table_name
```

and then,

```
Schema::table('table_name', function ($table) {
    $table->renameColumn('old_column_name', 'new_column_name');
});
```

run migration,

```
php artisan migrate
```